# Is it possible to get the IP address of an ODBC server?

Tags: odbc, ip-address

This is under Windows.  I can get the servername through a call to SQLGetInfo() but since I dont have the server name in my hosts file I cant use gethostbyname() to find its ip address.  Is there a method I am missing which would return back the IP address as defined in the ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog?

Comment: gethostbyname() doesn't work on windows? Odd... Windows is perfectly capable of doing DNS lookups... it ships with nslookup for command line operation, even.

Comment: It returned back a null BUT I doubt that the servername was in any DNS cache that I would have access to since it is an internal name on another companies lan that we can only access via IP.

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyname` is deprecated in favor of `getaddrinfo`. Use that instead.

Comment: How will getaddrinfo get the ip address of a system name that isnt in DNS or my hosts file?  I am trying to pluck the IP that was entered when I setup the data source.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood your question. It is not clear, I think, that you cannot use any usual name resolution method, you just state that it is not in your hosts file (which isn't really one of the usual methods nowadays, anyways). I assumed DNS was a possibility, sorry about that.

Comment: I didn't realize it until after I posted as to why my original test failed.  I was just hoping that there was some way to get the IP address from the Data Source config.